# Code Collaborator, Class' name change

Tags: java, code-collaborator

my scenario is: I have a class named "A.java", but now I'm realizing that "A" is not appropriate any more, so, I have changed it for "B.java", after I did this, I tried to create a code review for this change and other internal changes for that class, but I faced with an obviously thing: code Collaborator tool creates two different files and clearly it doesn't show as one, like I need it, would be great have a good suggestion, thanks in advance!

Ps: I've tried changing only the file name but this is causing various issues...